# Android Dev : Steps required for upgrading a manually installed app

Tags: android, tablet

I have built an android tablet application which is installed only from my web site - manual install.

I will need to be able to provide updates to existing users through the same site - without obliging users to uninstall the existing application.

What do I need to change in my (eclipse) project to permit this ?

Comment: What's the problem exacly? If you open the APK from the tablet it should overwrite the installed app (if the signature of the APK is not changed)

Comment: I get a message saying that there is an application with the same package name already installed.  It refuses to install the new apk.

Comment: The version of the new package is greater than the one of the old package? The app is signed or not?

Comment: What is happening is that the installed one and the new one are signed with different keys, so Android understands that they are different and trying to being installed in the same package, which is wrong

Comment: At the moment I am progressing from Debug to Release and needing to test - so version numbers are the same.  Yes the app is signed - both with the same key. It is copied to the tablet manually and then 'tapped' to install.

Comment: Have I understood correctly that the only thing I need to do to trigger an upgrade install (keeping all user settings and database content) is to change the version number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon -

Apps are designed to be upgraded in place on Android. All you need to do is ensure that the version number of the app being installed is greater than the previous version.

You can still provide debug releases, simply increment a portion of the version to reflect that change and your users can keep getting updates. Otherwise, you may want to have an explicitly Debug and Release version that can be installed side by side and not conflict with each other, but that may be more trouble and confusing than its worth.